# How to find with condition in NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

i have a controller that i want to search or find with condition. Can anybody help me or give me some suggestions so that i can find data with more conditions. Let me demonstrate my code below:

```
// Find all car with condition
export function findAllCar( req, res){
    const name = req.query.name;
    const color = req.query.color;
    const brand = req.query.brand;
    var condition = name ? { name: { [Op.iLike]: `%${name}%` } } : null;// Here i only can find with name, now i want to add more condition are color and brand

    Car.findAll({ where: condition })
      .then(data => {
        res.send(data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({
          message:
            err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving CARS."
        });
      });
}
```

How can i set the condition more with COLOR and BRAND. I am very appreciate for every help

Comment: You're going to have to add more details for us to understand the question

Comment: What database and/or library do you use to connect to your database?

Comment: Basically i just wanna know how to add the condition with COLOR and BRAND so i can find car with color and brand, not just only name.

Comment: My database is PostgreSQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a comma:

```
var condition = name && color && brand ? { 
    name: { [Op.iLike]: `%${name}%` },
    color: { [Op.iLike]: `%${color}%` },
    brand: { [Op.iLike]: `%${brand}%` },
} : null;
```